# D3 Graph - Add stroke to path

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have this code:

```
path = group.append("svg:path")
  .attr("d", arc)
  .style("fill", function(d) {
    if (d.children)
      return color(d.name)
    else
      return "grey"
  })
  .attr("display", function(d) {
    return d.depth ? null : "none";
  })
  .each(stash);
```

But I want to add not only the "fill" to the style but also a stroke, which is specifically this bit of code:

```
 .style("fill", function(d) {
    if (d.children)
      return color(d.name)
    else
      return "grey"
  })
```

Can anyone please tell me how to add a stroke to this? I can't do it in CSS since it needs to be specific to this particular path and it has no id or class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain multiple `style` or `attr` calls together (like you have with `fill` and `display` in your example) so does this achieve what you're looking for?

```
path = group.append("svg:path")
  .attr("d", arc)
  .style("fill", function(d) {
    if (d.children)
      return color(d.name);
    else
      return "grey";
  })
  .attr("stroke", function(d) {
    if (d.children)
      return "red";
  })
  .attr("stroke-width", function(d) {
     if (d.children)
       return 2;
     else 
       return 0;
  })
  .attr("display", function(d) {
    return d.depth ? null : "none";
  })
  .each(stash);
```

Seems like it would be much cleaner to apply a class based on the outcome of `d.children` though.